# Does dragging items defensively slow you down in Mario Kart 8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I just bought Mario Kart 8 and was playing with friends. Someone said it seems like he goes a little slower when dragging an item behind his kart to defend against attacks. Was that an optical illusion, or do you slow down? I don't think previous games had a penalty for item dragging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my own experience with the game, and from some searching around Google and the like, I cannot find any evidence to support your question. As the game currently plays, holding an item behind you does not slow your Kart down.

*Weirdly enough, the first result on Google when searching for an answer was a link to this question...*